# Not able to SSH into VM

Tags: ssh, centos, virtualbox

I want to SSH from my host into my guest VM (CentOS).
I can Ping.

SSH is running.
[image: SSH running]

Port 22 is open.
[image: Port 22 open]

Looks like firewall is off / IPtables are all open. (this is not normal?)[image]

When I SSH into my VM.
[image]

The password IS correct. When I login on VM directly, it works.
So I add this to /Users/robbertsegers/.ssh/known_hosts
[image]

But the problem reproduces.. Is that syntax correct?

Comment: check directory permission of .ssh and authorized_keys, run this `chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`

Comment: @Robbert Segers can you please post the contents of  /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

Comment: I ran directory permissions 'chmod 700 ~/.ssh' & 'chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*'. In sshd_conf is basically everything commented out.. What info do you need @vfbsilva?

Comment: @RobbertSegers do you have anything under AllowUsers?

Comment: Not found in sshd_config, also not in ssh_config.. Should I add that line, with IP from host?

Comment: Yeech. Don't take screenshots of text. Copy-paste.

Comment: I can't copy from guest VM to host, I don't have guestadditions installed. So I thought this was the better workaround.. instead of typing it all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "sudo" line, the "passwd" prompt is for your local password, not for the remote one.  It hasn't started running ssh yet because the sudo hasn't authenticated you yet.

Remove line 3 in your "known_hosts" file and try again.

Comment: You're right, thank you. passwd is ok now, it was for ssh. I've removed line 3 in known_hosts and problem moves to line 1. After commenting out all but right line, problem still reproduces.. even after commenting out all lines.

Comment: It looks like you have a non-default config so that unknown keys are not prompted to add try this: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=ask robbert@192.168.0.107.  It should prompt to add the key to known_hosts (you can say yes).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much bowlofred, I'd be searching for this for a long time.